# With AppleScript how do I tell when a external app is finished doing what I want

Tags: applescript

With AppleScript how do I tell when a external app is finished doing what I told it to do?

EG,

```
my DoStuff1()

my DoOtherAppThings()

my DoStuff2()
```

So, instead of using wait(10) I need something like:

```
my waitUntilOtherAppIsDone()

my DoStuff2()
```

Help accepted.

Comment: It would depend on what the application and command are.  AppleScript isn't multi-threaded, so unless ignoring application responses, it will usually wait for a response.

Comment: The app is BBEdit and the wait is for BBEdit to finish doing (1) over-writing a file and (2) saving the edit. I have gotten it to work with a delay(2) for each and it appears to work consistently. My problem is the realization that I had to continuously monkey with the delay time, the delay after writing and then the delay after saving. Yes it now works, but BBEdit should have the privilege of signaling when the writing is done and when the saving is done. OR MAYBE, it's System Events that can supply the signaling I am looking for?

Comment: There is also System Events' 'busy status'.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> The app is BBEdit and the wait is for BBEdit to finish doing (1) over-writing a file and (2) saving the edit.

There is no need to use a *delay* when telling **BBEdit** to *save* a *file* as any subsequent *command* does not trigger until the *save* is complete. Replacing (overwriting) an existing *file* of the same *name* is the *default*.

When executing, e.g., `tell application "BBEdit" to save front document to POSIX file "/path/to/untitled text 1.txt"` any subsequent *command* doesn't trigger until the *save* is complete. This is by design.

Here is a *screen shot* on **Script Editor** showing three *commands*, the first and third to show the date/time and the one in between **BBEdit** saving a 500 MB file. As you can see, it took 5 seconds after **BBEdit** started the *save* operation and *command* after it didn't trigger until the *save* operation completed.

[image]